# ExecuteScript ProcessLog

Tags: groovy, apache-nifi

What is the best way to utlize the ProcessorLog within an ExecuteScript processor? I was planning on adding some logging to my groovy ExecuteScript, if an error is encountered in the processing.  However, trying to add the log has been unsuccessful.  Probably overlooking something obvious.

Code Snippet:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils
import java.nio.charset.*
import com.google.gson.JsonObject
import com.google.gson.JsonParser
import java.time.Instant
import java.time.LocalDateTime
import java.time.ZoneId
import org.apache.nifi.logging.ProcessorLog;

def flowFile = session.get()
if(!flowFile) return
def logger = getLogger();
```

Error

```
016-04-07 17:13:51,146 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-6] o.a.nifi.processors.script.ExecuteScript
org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: javax.script.ScriptException: javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.getLogger() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: getContext()
        at org.apache.nifi.processors.script.ExecuteScript.onTrigger(ExecuteScript.java:205) ~[nifi-scripting-processors-0.5.1.jar:0.5.1]
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1139) [nifi-framework-core-0.5.1.jar:0.5.1]
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.call(ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.java:139) [nifi-framework-core-0.5.1.jar:0.5.1]
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.call(ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.java:49) [nifi-framework-core-0.5.1.jar:0.5.1]
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:124) [nifi-framework-core-0.5.1.jar:0.5.1]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_05]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308) [na:1.8.0_05]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_05]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294) [na:1.8.0_05]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_05]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_05]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_05]
Caused by: javax.script.ScriptException: javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.getLogger() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
```

Comment: Don't you need to either create an instance of logger or call a static `getInstance()` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe ExecuteScript makes three objects available:

- session
- context
- log

So I think you should be able to just do:

```
log.error("my message")
```

Comment: That was it.  Thanks Byran.